# Is Azure Storage REST API version "2015-07-08" used by storage client v7 documented anywhere?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I went to update the Azure storage client nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/), and before pulling it read the [changelog](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/changelog.txt). In the changelog they say "support for 2015-07-08 REST version. Please see our REST API documentation and blogs for information...". I have looked all over and can't find any documentation for that API version (2015-07-08) of what was changed. Does anyone know what was changed and/or where the changes are documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 7.x of the client library is based on version 2015-07-08 (the latest version). However, the change to the service with this version, as compared to version 2015-04-05, is very minor. The only change is the addition of the GetPageRangesDiff/GetPageRangesDiffAsync methods on CloudPageBlob. These methods support incremental snapshots (see https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/storage-incremental-snapshots/). There is no other change to the service.

Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691973.aspx for the change to Get Page Ranges.

We will provide information in the versioning section for 2015-07-08 soon.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find what was exactly changed, but I think the documentation refers to https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/tree/master/Documentation and blogs at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/.